# How to add conflicts in D8 info.yml?

Tags: 8, .info

I want to know how to add **conflicts** in D8 info.yml.

I tried like this in D8 .info.yml:

```
name: Example
type: module
description: some example.
core: 8.x
package: Other
dependencies:
  - menu_ui
conflicts:
  - module1
  - module2
```

and in .install file

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_requirements().
 */
function example_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = [];

  switch ($phase) {
    // Called while the module is installed.
    case 'install':
    if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('module1')) {
        $requirements[] = [
          'title' => t('Module 1'),
          'value' => t('Module 1'),
          'description' => t('Module 1 conflicts with example.'),
          'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR,
        ];
      }
      break;
  }

  return $requirements;
}
```

But in D7 it is working:

```
name = Example
description = some example.
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = menu
package = Other
conflicts[] = module1
conflicts[] = module2
```

While enabling my example module it is not showing any conflict error in D8.

> Installation Order:
>
> 1) Fresh Drupal installation.
>
> 2) Module 1
>
> 3) Module 2
>
> 4) Example module(here i need to show module1 and 2 are present while
>   installing)

Comment: It seems that this is not yet implemented. See [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/92233) issue.

Comment: ty for your comment, it saved my time.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this is not implemented yet. Related issue is [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/92233).

An alternative would be to use [`hook_requirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_requirements/8.2.x) in your module's `.install` file. You can check here if the conflicting module is present during the installation process and prevent the system from installing the module.

Here's example code that would go in your module's `.install` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_requirements().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = [];

  switch ($phase) {
    // Called while the module is installed.
    case 'install':
    // Called during regular use of the website.
    case 'runtime':
    // Called while the update.php is being executed.
    case 'update':
      // Do not allow administrators to install the module if conflicting module
      // is already installed.
      //
      // You can move this code to any other phase as well.
      if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('ARCH_ENEMY_OF_YOUR_MODULE')) {
        $requirements[] = [
          'title' => t('Name of your module'),
          'value' => t('Arch enemy module'),
          'description' => t('Explain that administrators need to uninstall the module before proceeding.'),
          'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR,
        ];
      }
      break;
  }

  return $requirements;
}
```

You can see a working example of `hook_requirements()` in my [Drupal 8 boilerplate repo on Github](https://github.com/aramboyajyan/drupal8-boilerplate/blob/master/boilerplate.install).

Hope this helps.

Comment: No luck, still not throwing any error while installing even though my module1 and 2 are installed.

Comment: Will have a look at it shortly

Comment: Just tested this - it's working properly and prevents you from installing the module if the conflicting module is already installed. Post your code if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: `<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_requirements().
 */
function example_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = [];

  switch ($phase) {
    // Called while the module is installed.
    case 'install':
    if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('module1')) {
        $requirements[] = [
          'title' => t('Module 1'),
          'value' => t('Module 1'),
          'description' => t('Module 1 conflicts with example.'),
          'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR,
        ];
      }
      break;
  }

  return $requirements;
}`

Comment: Code is not formatted properly in comments so it's better to post it to the question itself. However your code seems to be fine - are you sure that the machine name of the other module is `module1`?

Comment: Updated in question..
yes the other module name is **module1**

Comment: Something else is not right; I suggest doing this on a clean install. Also, just to clarify: when you add `hook_requirements()` to the `example` module, the system will prevent Example module from being installed. Can you write the order in which you are installing the modules?

Comment: Added installation order in question

Comment: Strange; I tested the code I posted and it works properly. I suggest trying this on another clean installation and seeing if other parts of your setup cause the problem. Here's what I would do: (1) remove any conditions and just prevent the module from installing; if this works fine, install Devel and check what is returned when you run this code: `\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('module1')`.